# Sort Algorithm First k element

Tags: c++

its give me the wrong output. what s the problem. 
       I want the sort the numbers exactly this way, how can I do it ?
      How can ı shift the array and insert the numbers to correct positions.

```
int a;
int N = 0;

cin >> N;  // Taking size of the inputs
int* numbers = new int[k];  // ı want the kth greatest number .
int x = 0;
while (x < k) {
    cin >> a;
    numbers[x] = a;
    x++;
}

int i, anahtar, j;  // after ı take k number from user, I Sort the numbers via insertion sort
for (i = 1; i < k; i++)
{
    anahtar = numbers[i];
    j = i - 1;


    while (j >= 0 && numbers[j] > anahtar)
    {
        numbers[j + 1] = numbers[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    numbers[j + 1] = anahtar;
}

// then I am taking other numbers one by one and ı am comparing with numbers in the array. After ı insert it the correct place, shifthing the array to the right

for (int e = x; e < N; e++) {
    cin >> a;
    if (a > numbers[k-1]) {
        for (int i = k-2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i == 0) {
                numbers[i+1] = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = a;
            }

            else if (a > numbers[i]) {
                numbers[i+1] = numbers[i];
            }
            else {
                numbers[i+1] = a;
            }
        } 

    }

}


return numbers[k -1];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is `std::nth_element` and sort in descending order.